# Get row data after an Update query

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, slim

I'm writing a very basic API that manages a list of existing unique keys. When the `getKey()` method is called, it either returns the key that has already been assigned or it finds one that is unused and assigns that.

During the latter, I have to call UPDATE on an existing row, marking it as assigned. After doing so, I am querying the same information again to get the row data, where I feel like this is fairly redundant. Although it works, I am trying to find the best practice for self improvement, where I would like to get any feedback on potentially better implementations.

```
<?php

require "Slim/Slim.php";
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

require "defines.php";

$GLOBALS['db'] = new mysqli(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS, DATABASE_NAME);

// SLIM INSTANCE
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/getKey/:dlc/:serviceId', function ($dlc, $serviceId)
{
    $sql = "SELECT game_key FROM " . $dlc . " WHERE service_id = " . $serviceId . " LIMIT 1";

    if ($result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql))
    {
        // Check if we already have a GAME_KEY assigned
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)
        {
            echo "got an existing row!";
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            echo $row["game_key"];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "no existing row, lets update one!";
            $sql = "UPDATE " . $dlc . " SET service_id = $serviceId WHERE service_id = 0 LIMIT 1";

            if ($GLOBALS['db']->query($sql))
            {
                $sql = "SELECT game_key FROM " . $dlc . " WHERE service_id = " . $serviceId;

                if ($result2 = $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql))
                {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
                    echo $row["game_key"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Query Failed!";
    }
});

// run the Slim app
$app->run();

?>
```

Comment: In the first part of your logic you check for a given **service_id** the  game_key is present, after that you are doing an update with where clause WHERE service_id = 0 and you are not setting the game_key . The game_key in the second query will be the same of the first. This second part looks like awkward. What do want with this code  ?

Comment: That is because the game_key fields are already set in the database. There are 1500 rows, each containing a unique game_key. I am just using service_id to determine if its assigned or not, where it is 0 if not, otherwise its the id of the service. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use max 2 statements:

```
// SELECT game_key matching $serviceId OR some with 0 if not found
$sql = "SELECT id, game_key, service_id FROM " . $dlc . " WHERE service_id = " . $serviceId . " OR service_id = 0 ORDER BY service_id DESC LIMIT 1";
if ($result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql))
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row["game_key"];
    // Check if it is new key
    if($row["service_id"] == 0) {
        $keyId = $row["id"]
        $sql = "UPDATE $dlc SET service_id = $serviceId WHERE id= $keyId LIMIT 1";
        ... // continue to exec update query
    }
}
```

I assume that you have "id" primary key column in your table

Comment: Thank you but I think the way I wrote it is confusing. Basically I need to first check and see if an existing row already exists with a specific "service_id". If it does, I get the "game_key" and echo that. If it doesn't, I need to find the first row that doesn't have a "service_id" set yet (i.e. value of 0) and assign it that "service_id".

Comment: That is why I have used ORDER BY statement - if there is row with this service_id this row will be returned. otherwise some with 0 will be returned - assuming that you have positive service_id values

Comment: Ah I completely missed that, makes perfect sense and looks very clean. Thank you!